# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I am trying to localize ActiveRecord error messages (Ukrainian language).
First, I set up application.rb file: **config.i18n.default_locale = :uk**
Second, I create a file **/config/locales/uk.yml**

There is such content in uk.yml:

```
uk:
  active_record:
    errors:
      messages:
        empty: "<some Ukrainian text>"
        blank: "<some Ukrainian text>"
```

Also, I know that for translating the error messages, Rails will use the following order of translations:

```
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
activerecord.errors.messages.blank
errors.attributes.name.blank
errors.messages.blank
```

But when I run an certain action I get the message:
**Email translation missing: uk.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank**

My question is **Why Doesn't the l18n search a translation at path activerecord.errors.messages.blank?**

Thank you.

Comment: You have `active_record`, not `activerecord` in your uk.yml. Is that a typo here or in your code?

Comment: ))) You are absolutely right. Sorry!

Comment: No worries. I'll add it as an answer so you can complete the Q&A process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `active_record`, not `activerecord` in your uk.yml